# Track updates on a SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server

To track the changes made to a table in SQL Server, I'm thinking of creating a history table that is exact replica of the table that is being tracked. When a update is made:

create a trigger after update and insert the record from deleted table to history table. To figure out what changed compare columns of main table with the history table.

Another approach is create a history table that has old_data (xml), new_data (xml). Both these columns contains data in XML format. The advantage of this approach is, when new columns added to the table, no need to change the history table structure. With this approach, how to find what changed?

Any other suggestions to track updates?

Comment: Possibly temporal tables, based on what are your requirements. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/temporal-tables?view=sql-server-ver16